# SQL Server 2012, a long column with XML format (varchar) in a table cannot be imported correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, xsd, sql-server-2012

I would like to export a table from SQL Server 2012 to a txt file .

One column (column 4) of the table is of type `varchar(max)` and its format is

```
<xs:element name="MyName" type="ns:namespace" /> // this line went to column 4
 <xs:complexType name="myName1"> // **this line went to column 1, but they should be in the column 4**
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="aName" type="xs:string"/>
 ....
```

It is very long with about 2000 characters. The other 3 columns are very short and all are varchar.

When I exported it as a txt file. The last column has newline added in the output text. So, when I imported it to another SQL Server 2012 database, the long row was broken  into multiple new lines so that the contents belonging to the long column was imported into the first column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you export the data to a text file, and how did you import the text file to the new database?  This can probably be solved by using field delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Use field delimiters in the export process so that the newline characters in the data will not be treated as newlines in the text file.